Get parent of element in Lua Pandoc filter
Is there a way to get the parent of an element, i.e. the element in which an element is in?
Use cases: when printing the traversal of the elements (show_level) or when checking whether a Str is in a ListItem (str_in_listitem). See my python example below.
If there is no parent in Lua, how are those use cases implemented in a Lua filter?
from panflute import *
from panflute.utils import debug

def get_level(elem: Element, level=0):
    if elem.parent is None:
        return level
    else:
        return get_level(elem.parent, level=level + 1)

def is_ancestor_of(elem: Element, clazz: Element):
    if elem.parent is not None:
        if type(elem.parent) == clazz:
            return True
        else:
            return is_ancestor_of(elem.parent, clazz)
    else:
        return False

def show_level(elem: Element, doc: Doc):
    debug("  " * get_level(elem) + elem.tag)

def str_in_listitem(elem: Element, doc: Doc):
    if type(elem) == Str:
        if is_ancestor_of(elem, ListItem):
            debug(stringify(elem))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_filters([show_level, str_in_listitem])

Appying this filter to the following input:
[ Para [ Str "some" , Space , Str "text" ]
, BulletList
    [ [ Plain [ Str "item1" ] ]
    , [ Plain [ Str "item2" ]
      , BulletList
          [ [ Plain [ Str "subitemA" ] ]
          , [ Plain [ Str "subitemB" ] ]
          ]
      ]
    ]
]

shows the following output for show_level:
  MetaMap
    Str
    Space
    Str
  Para
        Str
      Plain
    ListItem
        Str
      Plain
            Str
          Plain
        ListItem
            Str
          Plain
        ListItem
      BulletList
    ListItem
  BulletList
Doc

and the following for str_in_listitem:
item1
item2
subitemA
subitemB


One has to keep track manually. In rough strokes: one would use traverse: 'topdown' in the filter to make sure that all elements are visited in the right order. Then one might call current_element:walk with an appropriate filter. I'll try to write-up a full answer within the next days.

But often it isn't necessary to keep track of the global structure. E.g., to process only Str elements that are part of a bullet list one would write function BulletList (bl) return bl:walk{Str = my_str_filter} end

This only answers one part of the question: check whether a Str is in a ListItem. The answer implements @tarleb's comment in the question above.
@tarleb: please feel free to copy or adopt this to an own answer. I would then mark it accepted and delete my answer.
function uppercase_str_in_bullet_list(bullet_list)
    return bullet_list:walk{
        Str = function(str)
            str.text = pandoc.text.upper(str.text)
            return str, false
        end
    }
end

return {{
    BulletList = uppercase_str_in_bullet_list
}}

[ Para [ Str "some" , Space , Str "text" ]
, BulletList
    [ [ Plain [ Str "ITEM1" ] ]
    , [ Plain [ Str "ITEM2" ]
      , BulletList
          [ [ Plain [ Str "SUBITEMA" ] ]
          , [ Plain [ Str "SUBITEMB" ] ]
          ]
      ]
    ]
]


The answer to finding an elements depth is a bit complicated: pandoc's traversal methods don't have any hooks that would trigger on level changes, but implementing a custom traversal method would be a lot of work.
We take the middle road: we still let pandoc do most of the traversal, but we implement a custom hook into it. The functions and filters are mutually recursive, so the code is a bit confusing:
-- The level counter. Modified as we traverse the AST
local level = 0

-- A filter to bump the level. It's used recursively,
-- so it's only declared here, but defined later.
local bump_level_filter

-- Print the element tag, indented by `level` spaces.
-- Calls the `bump_level_filter` recursively
local print_tag = function (elem)
  print(string.rep(' ', level) .. elem.t)
  return elem:walk(bump_level_filter)
end

local bump_level = function (elems)
  level = level + 1
  local result = elems:map(print_tag)
  level = level - 1
  -- Return the elements unchanged, but DON'T continue
  -- walking to deeper levels. That's done manually
  -- in `print_tag`.
  return result, false
end

bump_level_filter = {
  traverse = 'topdown',
  Inlines = bump_level,
  Blocks = bump_level,
}

return {bump_level_filter}

The result isn't quite correct though, because the code doesn't account for nesting in list items etc. That would have to happen manually.
Using the input given above, the filter produces:
 Para
  Str
  Space
  Str
 BulletList
  Plain
   Str
  Plain
   Str
  BulletList
   Plain
    Str
   Plain
    Str


Thanks a lot. If I get it right, the trick is to hook in the topdown traversal (which in pandoc is depth-fist traversal), stop going down with _, false on every level, "visit" all siblings via List:map and start on every sibling again. So we get a breadth-first traversal. Amazing.

There is now a new Lua library that allows to do this: jog is a Lua-only reimplementation of pandoc's walk method. It is conceptually similar to panflute and such libraries, but also tries to stay close and mostly compatible with walk.
Jog allows to enable element contexts, which is then passed in as a second function argument:
--- show level

local jog = require 'jog'

--- Return the tag (e.g., `Str`) or type (e.g. `Meta`) of an element.
local function tag_or_type (x)
  return x.t or pandoc.utils.type(x)
end

local function print_context(element, context)
  print(table.concat(context:map(tag_or_type), '->'))
end

local show_level_filter = {
  context = true,   -- enable element contexts
  List = print_context,
  Inline = print_context,
  Block = print_context,
  Meta = print_context,
  Para = print_context,
}

function Pandoc(doc)
  return jog(doc, show_level_filter)
end

